# What is meant by CLR (Common Language Runtime) in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know the purpose of CLR with some real examples as I am a non computer science student.

Comment: Read a book by Jeffrey Richter, its probably the best deep-down explanation of the CLR.

Answer (score 2):

CLR (Common Language Runtime) is a runtime environment provided in every version of .NET framework that sits in between operating system and .NET application to do a variety of things. Such includes below

- Memory Management
- Thread Execution
- Garbage Collection
- Exception handling, etc.

It also allows the communication of various languages that .NET framework supports. For example, a class created from one language can be derived from another language. You can find more about it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr